# Eureka- Hiding row depending on ActionSheetRow value

Tags: swift, xcode, eureka-forms

I am trying to hide a row based on the value chosen in the ActionSheetRow before it .If the user picks they live in a cold climate I would like to hide or keep hidden the ActionSheetRow of where they would prefer to swim.

```
 func testForm(){
        form +++ Section("Test")
            <<< TextRow("Your Name"){
                $0.placeholder = "Enter Your Name"
        }
            <<< ActionSheetRow<String>("placeOfLiving") {
                $0.title = "Continent"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Where do you live?"
                $0.options = ["Antartica","Australia","Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", "South America"]

        }
            <<< ActionSheetRow<String>("swimming") {
                $0.hidden = Condition.function([])
                { form in
                    if let section = form.rowBy(tag: "placeOfLiving") as? ActionSheetRow<String> {
                        if section.value == "Antartica" {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
                $0.title = "Swimming"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Where do you like to swim?"
                $0.options = ["Pool","Beach","Lake", "River"]

        }

    }
```

How would I go about checking the value of the ActionSheetRow and then hiding the following row? I have attempted different ways on how to do this check but cannot find a similar scenario. Any feedback welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `tag` of the `rows` that you want to check for values inside `hidden` `function array` as below.

```
$0.hidden = Condition.function(["rowTag"])
```

So, your code will become,

```
$0.hidden = Condition.function(["placeOfLiving"])
   { form in
      if let row = form.rowBy(tag: "placeOfLiving") as? ActionSheetRow<String> {
          return section.value == "Antartica"
       }
       return false
   }
```